# All the elements in NSMutableArray disappear after copying

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, nsmutablearray

I am initializing a view controller with a NSMutableArray. But in init, I have to init with NSMutableArray, but all the elements disappeared after that.

```
UIViewController* vc = [[[PhotoAlbumViewController alloc] initWithImages:imageArrayBig] autorelease];
```

Below is the definition of the function above.

```
// This is the definition of the init function
- (id)initWithImages:(NSMutableArray *)bigImages {

    if ((self = [self initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil])) {
        _imageArrayBig = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (ArrayObject* tmp in bigImages) {
            [_imageArrayBig addObject: tmp];
        }
    }
    // After the copying, all the elements in bigImages and _imageArrayBig disappear :(
    return self;
}
```

Any idea? Is there a memory leak?

Comment: Sorry that I have confused you guys. They are in fact two separate pieces of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing the property name with the instance name since you use both `imageArrayBig` and `_imageArrayBig`.

It is better to stick with one, preferably `self.imageArrayBig` which is the property

You can also copy the array more effectively by using `addObjectsFromArray`

something like

```
NSMutableArray* tmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[tmp addObjectsFromArray:bigImages];
self.imageArrayBig = tmp;
[tmp release];
```

Comment: I didn't make a property and synthesize imageArrayBig. _imageArrayBig is simply the private variable of the object class. It is really needed to make a property and synthesize it?

Comment: And in fact, I have tried addObjectsFromArray before, but failed. Anyway, I will try again your code later.

Comment: I have implemented the function as what you said. But I got "Program received signal: EXC_BAD_ACCESS" when I do "NSLog(@"[debug] %@", [self.imageArrayBig count]);"

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is fine but can be optimized as @anders suggests. You don't need a property. Are you sure that `bigImages` has objects in it when you pass to init? Add an NSLog to verify:

```
- (id)initWithImages:(NSMutableArray *)bigImages {
    self = [self initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"MyController:initWithImages: bigImages count = %d", [bigImages count]);
        _imageArrayBig = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:bigImages];
    }
    return self;
}
```

It's also not clear why you need to pass in a mutable array. If you are creating a new mutable array you can pass in an `NSArray`.

Comment: Because the object passing in is originally a mutable array. Yes, I confirm that there are objects inside bigImages by NSLog. I got "Program received signal: EXC_BAD_ACCESS" when I do "NSLog(@"[debug] %@", [_imageArrayBig count]);" after init. So frustrating.

Comment: You can pass an `NSMutableArray` to a method that takes an `NSArray`. You should do that here as the `initWithImages` method does not require the array passed in to be mutable. That's not your crash though. Your NSLog is wrong. You need to specify %d for an integer arg. %@ expects to be replaced by an object.

Comment: glad you got your code working but it's not clear why @anders answer helped you based on your original code. You didn't have a property and were setting an alloc'ed array to your ivar. that's perfectly valid code.